# DIV responding to length of username

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have this log-out link where it echoes your username from when you logged in + a | and Logout. An example would be "ilikepizza | Log out". But I'd like it so the div around the link responds to the width of the username, which it doesn't. So if somebody had a long username it would automatically fit within the DIV.

Here's the code (css included):

```html
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
?>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="pictures/vinyl_gb_vinyl-600x600.png"/>
 <title>
  website.com
 </title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <style>
 b { font-weight: bold; }
     BODY { background-image: url(pictures/background.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; }
 a {color: white; font-family: Geosans; text-decoration:none;}
  .loggedin{ width: 9vw;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .loggedin:hover {background-color: #111;}
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </style>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
      session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
     echo '<div class="loggedin">';
     echo '<a href="Jukebox/logout.php">';
     $username = $_SESSION['username'];
     $username = $_SESSION['username'];
     echo $username;
     echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Log out</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
       else{
         echo '';
    }
    ?>
```

Anyone know how to do this? I've tried multiple things but no dice.
EDIT: *don't run it, it doesn't register you being logged in. I only used it to show you the code.*

Comment: You probably want to float your block or make it an inline-block instead of setting a width.

Comment: I tried setting `display: inline-block` but that only made it worse.

Comment: There are too many possible answers and I think the most HTML is missing in your example. Could you make an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: Using a code snippet doesn't work with php. You should remove the php and make an example with just html and css. And explain how `inline-block` makes it worse.

Comment: Inline block makes the text go outsode the block

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `width` property in the css for `.loggedin`. This gives the object a static width.

```
.loggedin { 
    /* width: 9vw; Don't set a static width */
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I know that, that was a temporary solution.

Comment: It should work without the static width. Can you post a screenshot of what the result is without the width property? That way I can see what exactly is going on.

Comment: I would add display: inline-block. So it fits to the content, but has still the porperties of a blocked element. At the end it depends on the parent elements. I think the most HTML is missing in the example of Maarten to give a good answer.

Comment: here's what it looks like without the static width [screenshot](https://snag.gy/AKHtqg.jpg) And also, the rest of the page has nothing really to do with logout button, so that's why i don't show it.